# How to enable all the hint movies in New Super Mario Bros. Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii, new-super-mario-bros-wii

I've got all star coins (including World 9) but not all the movies from the castle are available. What should I do to enable them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GameFAQs has [list](http://www.gamefaqs.com/wii/960544-new-super-mario-bros-wii/faqs/58584) of all of them and how to unlock them. Permission has not been granted to replicate the information here.

Comment: That's a great resource @DavRob60!